# In OpenCart, how to get current product id, name and image?

Tags: php, opencart

In opencart, i need to get these infos about the current product:

- Id
- Name
- Image

In magento, I only do this, but in opencart, i just don't know:

```
<?php if($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>

  <?php echo $_product->getId() ?>
  <?php echo $_product->getName() ?>
  <?php echo $_product->getImageUrl() ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Oh, if You can do this in Magento (**in the template!**) then I am really glad I am not using that piece of crap... In OpenCart You have to do it the normal and clean MVC way - edit the controller, make the product visible (assign it) to template and then normally echo it in the template... It also depends on where do You want this to happen? In the products detail page? Or where?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to get in details product page. For example: http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40

I think this is already visible, but I don't know how to get these infos

Comment: to get these infos where? Open up the template for this and You'll see... You can directly access something like `$description` or `$price` or `$product_info['title']` I guess... Just open the template `catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl` and You'll see.

Comment: I endup using:
    `<?php echo $product_id; ?>
    <?php echo $heading_title; ?>
    <?php echo $popup; ?>`

Answer (score 3):

I endup using:

```
<?php echo $product_id; ?> //returns product id
<?php echo $heading_title; ?> //returns product name
<?php echo $popup; ?> //returns product image
```